# Too many redirects .htaccess cpanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

Hi i have an htaccess file that gave me the browser error too many redirects

This is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^registro\.pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.registro\.pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx\/registration\.php" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/pueblo\.servicios\.org\.mx" [R=301,L]
```

Is something bad formated?

Comment: You have a rewrite loop. To avoid this loop, you must add some stop condition. It is not clear, what you want to achieve with these rules.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end?